# Modern list view does not correctly group and sort items

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, modern-experience, group-by

I have set up a view (modern experience) on a list in a SharePoint Online site, grouping by a 'Meeting Date' column and sorting on a 'Time' column (ascending order) then 'Requirement' column (ascending order).

I and other users are seeing incorrect items being placed into each grouping, and items being sorted in the wrong order within each group. There is no apparent pattern to the order (i.e. it is not falling back to a sort on 'ID' or other columns).

'Meeting Date' is a Calculated Column, which looks up a 'Meeting' (Date & Time) column and returns as Date only. 'Time' is also a Calculated Column, which extracts the time from the 'Meeting' column and returns as Text. Finally, 'Requirement' is a Lookup column returned as Text.

I have kept all other view settings as close to the SharePoint defaults as possible. Is there anything I have missed which may be causing the items to appear in the wrong order, or could this be a SharePoint bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I test in my environment based on the same column types and few items, all the group and sort order is display correctly.

Please narrow down your issue as following:

1. How many items in the list view? Large number of items in the list might cause the wrong display in the view.
2. Clear the sort in the list view, check if the Group By works correctly.
3. You can also clear all the view settings, then add group by or sort one by one to check which settings might cause the issue.

Comment: Thank you. I tried changing the view settings and although these didn't fix the issue, recreating the view from scratch with the same settings fixed the problem.I believe that the original view was created with the style 'Shaded' and even though this was reverted to 'Default', that the 'Shaded' style caused the view to work incorrectly.